# Kubernetes podaffinity rule to match either label on another pod

Tags: kubernetes

Using k8s: v1.23.9

I'd like the Pod to be scheduled on a node that has a pod with either of the labels in the PodAffinity constraint.

I want the rules to work in a logical-OR manner. I.e schedule below pod on a node that has a pod with either labels:

version_from: bbbb6666 or
version_to: bbbb6666

Instead, K8s is treating this as a logical-AND!

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: with-pod-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
     podAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:    
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: version_from
            operator: In                   
            values:
            - bbbb6666    
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname          
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: version_to
            operator: In                   
            values:
            - bbbb6666    
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname          
  containers:
  - name: with-pod-affinity
    image: registry.k8s.io/pause:2.0
```

Comment: Good question and use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.   My requirement is that I do not want the Pod to be scheduled if either labels are not found.  In your example below, The k8s scheduler could ignore the constraint as it is preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution and not requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution? Correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Pods are also to be scheduled if either label is not found. I tried a scenario that covered both of them, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I found a different way, explained in the answer below (updated). If you change the key:value, it works with Logical OR + "Pod not to be scheduled if either labels are not found". I tested it on my setup, it works with this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you organize your keys like below, it is possible to run as Logical OR. I tried the 4 different scenarios below, please have a look at them.

**From:**

```
version_from: bbbb6666
version_to:   bbbb6666
```

**To:**

```
version: bbbb6666_from
version: bbbb6666_to
```

Because, K8s allows to use of multiple values, but does not allow to use of multiple keys.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: with-pod-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
    podAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution::
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: version
            operator: In
            values:
            - bbbb6666_from
            - bbbb6666_to
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
  containers:
  - name: with-pod-affinity
    image: registry.k8s.io/pause:2.0
```

**Test Scenario:**

Added 2 more nodes:

```
minikube node add  # new node: minikube-m02
minikube node add  # new node: minikube-m03
```

I run nginx on 2 different machines, cache pod with equal weight runs on randomly **minikube-m02** OR **minikube-m03**:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: frontendpod
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/hostname: "minikube-m02"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: frontendpodv2
  labels:
    app: frontendv2
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/hostname: "minikube-m03"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cachepod
spec:
  affinity:
    podAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: app
            operator: In
            values:
            - frontend
            - frontendv2
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
  containers:
  - name: cachecontainer
    image: redis:6-alpine
```

Tested Scenarios:

```
Scenario1 => app:frontend, app:frontendv2 => cachepod runs  (randomly on one of the node)
Scenario2 => app:frontendv3, app:frontendv2 => cachepod runs (near to frontend2)
Scenario3 => app:frontend, app:frontendv4 => cachepod runs (near to frontend)
Scenario4 =>app:frontendv3, app:frontendv4 => cachepod pending
```

**Output (Scenario1):**

[image]

**Output (Scenario2):**

[image]

**Output (Scenario3):**

[image]

**Output (Scenario4: Pending):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, not quite what I was looking for. But it may work for my usecase.